# Interface programming for LinkedLists

Tags: java, interface

I was recently pointed to this question ([What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)) and wanted to get some clarification.

```
LinkedList<Integer> test1 = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
List<Integer> test2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

From what I've read, the first LinkedList/List determines what methods can be used. So for test1, you can do test1.peek() while you can't for test2. Is that because, for test2, that you are creating a LinkedList but going to be implementing the methods of the List interface? In other words, for test2, you've created a LinkedList with a prev & next node but are choosing to implement the methods outlined in the List interface?

Guess I'm a bit confused because I thought LinkedList is a class that implements the List interface, but for test2, we're creating a LinkedList and implementing a List again?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your question correctly. Is it about what methods are accessible on `test2`? If so, it is really the same concept as it is with inheritance: the static type of the variable defines what methods can be accesed. Thus, for `test2` one can only call methods defined in `List`.

Comment: Both lines create a full `LinkedList`, nothing is missing. You have to differentiate variables from instances. In your code 2 `LinkedList` instances are created and `2` variables are created. `test1` is a variable that is allowed to refer to `LinkedList` instances. `test2` is a variable allowed to refer to `List` instances. As a `LinkedList` **is** a `List` as well, the variable is allowed to point to that as well. Think about `Animal animal = new Dog();`, its the same with inheritance.

Comment: When coding to the interface, you are using the methods that are present on the interface (a la ```test2```). When you use the concrete class (```test1```), you are able to use the methods of both the interface (```List```) and the concrete class (```LinkedList```). You can use ```test2``` like a ```LinkedList``` by casting, but of course it could break if ```test2``` is instantiated with another type (e.g. ```ArrayList```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've read, the first LinkedList/List determines what methods
> can be used.

Yes, the "first LinkedList/List" is *the type of the reference* you are declaring.  You can invoke the methods exposed by a reference's type on that reference, including inherited ones, and no others.

> So for test1, you can do test1.peek() while you can't for
> test2.

Yes.

> Is that because, for test2, that you are creating a LinkedList
> but going to be implementing the methods of the List interface?

No.  *You* are not implementing anything there.  You are initializing references `test1` and `test2` to refer to objects of *class* `LinkedList`, which is a concrete class that `implements` `List`, and therefore provides concrete implementations of all methods defined by the `List` interface.  `LinkedList` also provides implementations of some methods defined by other interfaces and by superclasses, and, in principle, it could define and implement some methods unique to it.

> In
> other words, for test2, you've created a LinkedList with a prev & next
> node but are choosing to implement the methods outlined in the List
> interface?

Again, you are not implementing any methods here.  By choosing to access a `LinkedList<Integer>` object via a reference of type `List<Integer>`, you ensure that only those `LinkedList` methods that are defined by `List` can be invoked via that reference.  That doesn't change the nature of the object itself.  There will be other references to it at least sometimes, some of them of type `LinkedList<Integer>`.  Those can be used to invoke methods exposed by `LinkedList` but not by `List` on the object.

> Guess I'm a bit confused because I thought LinkedList is a class that
> implements the List interface,

Yes.

> but for test2, we're creating a
> LinkedList and implementing a List again?

Every `LinkedList` *is* a `List`.  This is one of the main consequences of the fact that former class `implements` the latter interface.  By accessing an object of class `LinkedList` via a reference of type `List`, you limit yourself to using only those parts of it that are defined by `List`, but you have not changed the object itself in any way.  It is still a `LinkedList`.

Consider human roles.  I'm a son, a brother, a father, an employee, a friend, and many other things, but most people in my life interact with me according to only one or two of those roles.  For example, my boss regularly asks me, her employee, to do various pieces of work for her, but she would never ask me to give her a weekly allowance as if I were her father.

Types, and in particular interface types, can be regarded like those roles.  If you need an employee, it doesn't have to be someone exactly like me -- it can be anyone who can fill the "employee" role.  And operating in that role does not make anyone not have all their other roles.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList implements List;
List does not implement LinkedList.

`peek` is a method of a `LinkedList`,
but is not a method of `List`.

Because of this situation, `test2.peek()` is a compile time error.

Specifically,
test2 only exposes the functionality of a List.

Comment: "*LinkedList is a superset of List*" - It is the other way around: Every `LinkedList` is a `List`, but not every `List` is a `LinkedList`. Thus `List` is the superset of `LinkedList`.

Comment: The set of methods of `LinkedList` is a superset of the set of methods of `List`.  The set of `List`s is a superset of the set of `LinkedList`s.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other correct answers, I'd like to point out what the compiler ensures:

```
LinkedList<Integer> test1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Here the compiler will make sure that anyting assigned to `test1` fulfills the `LinkedList` interface.

```
List<Integer> test2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Here the compiler will make sure that anyting assigned to `test2` fulfills the `List` interface 'only'.

While that means you cannot call methods of the `LinkedList` interface on `test2`, it gives the flexibility to assign any implementation of `List` to it without changing any user of it.

That said: if you do not need specific types (interfaces), you should use a more common type instead to stay more flexible.
So if you only want to know the size and iterate the elements, you could use `Collection` - but this will not allow to access the 3rd element easily.